# SwiftData @Query crashes when trying to filter or sort using an enum or relationship

Tags: swift, swift-data

Like the title says, I've realised that when I try to use filter or sort on properties that aren't standard supported data types i.e. using a transformable or a value type like an enum, I seem to be getting the following crash...

`SwiftData/DataUtilities.swift:1140: Fatal error: Unexpected type for Expansion: Optional<UIColor>`

Xcode expands and shows me when trying to access the wrapped value it's crashing. I'm assumung that the query property wrapper can't handle these custom data types

```
    @Query private var items: [Item]
{
    get {
        _items.wrappedValue // <--- Crash here
    }
}
```

Which seems to be pointing to a transferable property in one of my models. Below are my two models i'm using.

```
enum Priority: Int, Codable, Identifiable, CaseIterable {
    case low
    case medium
    case high
    
    var title: String {
        switch self {
        case .low:
            return "Low"
        case .medium:
            return "Medium"
        case .high:
            return "High"
        }
    }
    
    var image: Image? {
        switch self {
        case .medium:
            return Image(systemName: "exclamationmark.2")
        case .high:
            return Image(systemName: "exclamationmark.3")
        default:
            return nil
        }
    }
    
    var id: Self { self }
}

@Model
final class Item: Codable {
    var title: String
    @Attribute(originalName: "timestamp")
    var dueDate: Date
    var isCompleted: Bool
    
    var isFlagged: Bool = false
    var isArchived: Bool = false
    
    var isCritical: Bool?
    
    var priority: Priority?
    
    @Relationship(deleteRule: .nullify, inverse: \Category.items)
    var category: Category?
    
    @Attribute(.externalStorage)
    var image: Data?
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case title
        case timestamp
        case isCritical
        case isCompleted
        case category
        case imageName
    }
    
    
    init(title: String = "",
         dueDate: Date = .now,
         priority: Priority? = nil,
         isCompleted: Bool = false) {
        self.title = title
        self.dueDate = dueDate
        self.priority = priority
        self.isCompleted = isCompleted
    }
    
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        self.title = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .title)
        self.dueDate = Date.randomDateNextWeek() ?? .now
        self.isCompleted = try container.decode(Bool.self, forKey: .isCompleted)
        self.category = try container.decodeIfPresent(Category.self, forKey: .category)
        
        if let imageName = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .imageName),
           let imageData = UIImage(named: imageName) {
            self.image = imageData.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.8)
        }
        
        if let isCritical = try container.decodeIfPresent(Bool.self, forKey: .isCritical),
           isCritical == true {
            self.priority = .high
        }
        
    }
    
    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        try container.encode(title, forKey: .title)
        try container.encode(dueDate, forKey: .timestamp)
        try container.encode(isCompleted, forKey: .isCompleted)
        try container.encode(category, forKey: .category)
    }
}

@Model
class Category: Codable {
    
    @Attribute(.unique)
    var title: String
    
    var items: [Item]?
    
    @Attribute(.transformable(by: ColorValueTransformer.self))
    var color: UIColor?
    
    init(title: String = "",
         color: UIColor) {
        self.title = title
        self.color = color
    }
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case title
    }
    
    required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        self.title = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .title)
        self.color = UIColor(possibleColors.randomElement()!)
    }
    
    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        try container.encode(title, forKey: .title)
    }
}
```

And below is an example of me sorting based on my enum (Priority) & Relationship (Category name)

```
func sort() -> [SortDescriptor<Item>]{
    switch self {
    case .title:
        [SortDescriptor(\Item.title)]
    case .date:
        [SortDescriptor(\Item.dueDate)]
    case .category:
        [SortDescriptor(\Item.category?.title)]
    case .priority:
        [SortDescriptor(\Item.priority?.rawValue)]
    }
}
```

And a filter example below creating a predicate that we will execute to return and matches found in the title or category title

```
let highPriority = Priority.high
if let query {
    return #Predicate {
        $0.priority == highPriority &&
        ($0.title.contains(query) || $0.category?.title.contains(query) == true) &&
        $0.isArchived == false
    }
}
```

I'm pretty sure this is a SwiftData bug since when using basic data types like strings, bools and dates it's all fine, using anything outside of that box causes these crashes...

Comment: I also have had crashes or compilation errors when trying to use an enum or relationship property in a predicate although without any transformable property involved. Since I have used these properties in a straightforward manner in my predicates I agree this looks like a SwiftData bug.

Comment: Yh I think the both the transformable & enums just aren’t handled properly atm. Hopefully in the next update this gets sorted

Comment: Feedback filed FB13202320